# Boost function composition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function, function-composition

Suppose I want to have a function `double adapter(double)`, is there a general way to compose it with a `boost::function<double(...)> functor` to produce another `boost::function<double(...)> functor2` where `functor2(...) == adapter(functor(...))`? In particular, it would be cool if there was a way to do this without using C++11.

**edit** To clarify, I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to write something that can handle any `boost::function<double(...)>`, i.e. ones that have different length signatures without having to copy and paste multiple times for 1, 2, 3, etc. arguments.

Comment: Supporting different number of arguments isn't a walk in the park in C++03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without c++11, there are a significant number of complexities, including the varadic arguments and forwarding.

With C++11, it can be done, mostly by specializaing `std::is_bind_expression`.  When this function object is used in a bind, it calls the function object that was stored with all of the arguments that were provided during the call to the bound function object.  Note, this works with any function object, not just `std::function`.

This works with GCC 4.7.

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
template<typename Func>
struct compose_functor
{

   Func f;

   explicit compose_functor(const Func& f) : f(f) {};

   template<typename... Args>
   auto operator()(Args&&... args) const -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
   {
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }

};

}

template<typename Func>
 detail::compose_functor
<Func> compose(Func f)
{
   return detail::compose_functor<Func>(f);
}


namespace std
{
   template<typename T>
   struct is_bind_expression< detail::compose_functor<T> > : true_type {};
}
#include <numeric>

int adapter(double d)
{
    return (int)d;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(double)> f1 = std::bind(adapter, compose(std::negate<double>()));
    std::function<int(double, double)> f2 = std::bind(adapter, compose(std::plus<double>()));

    // 1.5 -> -1.5 -> -1
    std::cout << f1(1.5) << std::endl;
    // 2.3+4.5 = 6.8 -> 6
    std::cout << f2(2.3, 4.5) << std::endl;
}
```